# How to call a method between different objects in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm developing an application for mobile devices using the DHTMLX-touch framework, which is basically javascript.

I have a class A where this function is implemented:

```
A.prototype.initEventHandler = function(controller) {
    $$('btn_submit').attachEvent('onItemClick', controller.switchView($$('ui_ewmon_main')));
}
```

**First implementation**

the object controller is an instance of the class B, and the class B is the following:

```
function B() {     
    //back button management
    this.last_view=new Array();
    this.current_view=this.ewmon_view.getRoot();

    this.switchView = function(next) {
        this.last_view[this.last_view.length]=this.current_view;
        this.current_view=next;
        next.show();
    }
}
```

with firebug i get this error:

> A.js:32Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'switchView'

**Second implementation**

if I try to define switchView function as a prototype function:

```
function B() {     
    //back button management
    this.last_view=new Array();
    this.current_view=this.ewmon_view.getRoot();
}
B.prototype.switchView = function(next) {
    this.last_view[this.last_view.length]=this.current_view;
    this.current_view=next;
    next.show();
}
```

in this case I get the following error:

> B.js:13Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance
Danilo

Comment: Are you using `new` to create the instance of `B`?

Comment: im creating the Bobject in the constructor of A object as:

this.b = new B();

anyway the Prusse's solution worked for me.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `attachEvent` with the return of `controller.switchView($$('ui_ewmon_main'))`, to get the result you seen to want do:

```
A.prototype.initEventHandler = function(controller) {
    $$('btn_submit').attachEvent('onItemClick', function(){ controller.switchView($$('ui_ewmon_main')); });
}
```

Edit:

Looking at the code you posted I will expect this error to show up. From the line `this.current_view=this.ewmon_view.getRoot();` one will guess `this.current_view` is always an object like the one returned by `EWmonView.prototype.getRoot`(rigth?), but this object don't have a method `show`.

But you call `controller.switchView($$('ui_ewmon_main'));` causing `this.current_view` to be whatever is `$$('ui_ewmon_main')`, keeping different object types in the array `this.last_view` and `this.current_view` is the source of the mistake.

A dirty fix will be:

```
if (this.current_view.show) {
    this.current_view.show();
} else{
    $$('ui_ewmon_main').show(); //or $$('ui_ewmon_login').show() can tell what you want =)
}
```

In the place of the occurrences of `this.current_view.show();` in EWmonController. But rework the code and get `this.current_view` to have always the same kind of objects looks like better to me.

Comment: Thanks Prusse,the solution worked well. Now I added the back function in the initEventHandler method:

`$$('btn_back').attachEvent('onItemClick', function(){
 controller.lastView();
});`

and in the B object I added:

`B.prototype.lastView = function() {
 this.current_view=this.last_view[this.last_view.length-1];
 delete this.last_view[this.last_view.length-1];
 this.current_view.show();
}`

when I click on btn_submit I can switch the view (calling the method show()), but after, when I click on btn_back I get

**B.js:23Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'show'**
Help please.

Comment: Hi Prusse, you can find the 2 classes at this address the [A class](http://jsfiddle.net/XJxEc/) and here the [B class](http://jsfiddle.net/wf47t/). Tjanks in advance